# clearInterval not working in componentWillUnmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react app fetching api and setInterval in componentDidMount and remove it in componentWillUnmount, but somehow even when component no longer mount (ex. when user logout and redirected to login page) it still execute fetch api periodically, how to debug it?

(1) fetch api code

```
fetchApi = async pathname => {
const URL = 'API URL'
try {
  const { data } = await axios.get(URL, { withCredentials: true });
  const { updateTime, results } = data;
  const sortedResults = _.sortBy(results, "wo_start").reverse();

  // fetching user data from sessionStorage
  const user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("user"));
  if (!user) {
    return this.setState({
      redirectToLogin: true
    });
  }
  return this.setState({
    orders: sortedResults,
    renderedOrders: sortedResults,
    updateTime: updateTime.time,
    pathname,
    user
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Credentials Failed");
  return this.setState({
    redirectToLogin: true
  });
}};
```

(2) componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount() {
const { pathname } = this.props.history.location;
this.fetchApi(pathname)
  .then(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(
      () => this.fetchApi(pathname),
      2 * 60 * 1000
    );
    this.setState({
      intervalId: intervalId
    })
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
  }
```

(3) componentWillUnmount

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
// clearing set interval
clearInterval(this.state.intervalId);
};
```

(4) here is image from chrome console after logout
[image: chrome console after logout]

Comment: I'd start by `console.log`ging around `componentWillUnmount`, does that block run as expected?

Comment: yeah maybe `componentWillUnmount` is not even running. Try logging, or setting a breakpoint, the value of `this.state.intervalId` too

Answer (score 0):

**setState() is async.**

change your code:

(2) componentDidMount

```
 ...
 ...
  this.fetchApi(pathname)
  .then(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(
    () => this.fetchApi(pathname),
    2 * 60 * 1000
  );
  this.intervalId= intervalId
...
...
```

(3) componentWillUnmount

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  // clearing set interval
  clearInterval(this.intervalId);
};
```

Comment: *setState() is async* - so is a promise. It's very unlikely that setState causes race condition.